# Equivalent to markermft='C0x' in matplotlib 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.stem(np.arange(10), np.ones(10), 'C0-', markerfmt='C0x')
plt.show()
```

[image]

but I've been told it does not work with matplotlib 1.

I replaced `C0-` by `b-`, but the blue is less esthetic IMO:
[image]

How could I select the color I want, with an hex code, while being matplotlib 1 compliant?

Trying to specify the color with `linefmt='#ff7f0e-'` doesn't work either

```
ValueError: Unrecognized character # in format string
```

and arguments such a `c`, `markerfacecolor` are not recognised by `plt.stem`

Edit:
I can do:

```
m, s, b = plt.stem(...)
plt.setp([m, s], color='#ff7f0e')
```

but it seems weird to not be able to set the color directly in the stem call, doesn't it?